# Prove a set is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let the set S be a collection of all x in R such that |x|>1. Show that the set is open.

I was thinking about taking some b within the set. Then constructing an open ball with radius (b-1)/2. Therefore the ball is open. Since the set is contained within S, then the Set s is also open.

Comment: Your approach is a good idea, although you have to be careful here, since $b$ could be less than $0$. You could, however, choose the radius to be $(|b|-1)/2$, and proceed from there.

Comment: $(|b|-1)/2$ can be negative. Take radius $ r=|b-1|/2 .$

Comment: @user254665 $(|b|-1)/2$ cannot be negative since it was assumed that $|b|>1$

Comment: sorry about that..................

Answer (score 1):

A quick way:

Note that the set $S := \{ x \in \Bbb{R} \mid |x| > 1 \}$ is simply the preimage of the set $]1, +\infty[$, open in $\Bbb{R}$, under the continuous map $x \mapsto |x|$; hence $S$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$ too.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea works for $b>1$, but $b$ could be negative and then you need $\frac{|b|-1}{2}$ instead. You need to formally show that $B(b, \frac{|b|-1}{2}) \subseteq S$. So pick $x$ in the ball and show it is in $S$ as well.

Or note that $S = (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$ and show both parts to be open separately, e.g. $(1, \infty) = \cup_{n=1}^\infty (n,n+2)$ which is a union of open intervals, hence open.